# What's the term for the investment/yield ratio?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

One online-dictionary says it is

> *input-output ratio*

But to me, that doesn't convey the idea of *investment* & *yield* at all.

BTW, the corresponding Chinese is "投入产出比", just for people to search, in case they need.

Comment: There are many different terms for measuring different types of return on investment. Is there any further detail you can add? See e.g. the Wikipedia article concerning [financial ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_ratio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia :

**Rate of return** is a profit on an investment over a period of time, expressed as a proportion of the original investment. The time period is typically a year, in which case the rate of return is referred to as annual return.

**Return on investment** (ROI) is return per dollar invested.

Is that it ?

Comment: Are you certain this is the right translation, and not ROA, ROIC, ROE, etc.?

Comment: Actually, I know nothing about economics. Can't say.

Comment: @choster, thanks for the wiki link. _"Is there any further detail you can add?"_, no, actually, it's a very simple question, regarding the value/effort I put in vs the value/outcome I get out of it, and I'd like to know the most common used way to express it. I.e., ROI would be the perfect one for it, that everyone would understand it as-is. As for ROA, ROIC, ROE, etc, I never heard of them, so I think they'd be the economics jargon that only few would understand, thus not the ones that I was looking for. Thanks for helping though.